# TSQL variable assignment in the "then" of select case when

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, case

I'm trying to SET a variable with other variables using a case when condition that comes from a select:

```
DECLARE @var_to_be_set INT
DECLARE @var1 INT
DECLARE @var2 INT

SELECT
  CASE WHEN col = 1 THEN @var_to_be_set = col + @var1
       WHEN col = 2 THEN @var_to_be_set = col + @var2
  END
FROM table [etc..etc..]
```

Is this possible? I keep having Incorrect syntax errors in every way I try.
Tried a solution on google, but can't find anything relevant.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you must remember that `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that can return one atomic value (depending on some conditions) - it is **NOT** a flow control statement! You cannot execute blocks of code in your `WHEN...THEN...` path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can assign value to variable with `CASE`:

```
DECLARE @var_to_be_set INT
DECLARE @var1 INT               -- intialize variables with values
DECLARE @var2 INT

SELECT @var_to_be_set = 
  CASE WHEN col = 1 THEN col + @var1
       WHEN col = 2 THEN col + @var2
  END
FROM table [etc..etc..]
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411090)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that if your query returns multiple rows, you will get only one value.

Shorter version:

```
SELECT @var_to_be_set = col + CASE col 
                              WHEN 1 THEN @var1 
                              WHEN 2 THEN @var2 
                              END
...
```

or even (`SQL Server 2012+`):

```
SELECT @var_to_be_set = col + CHOOSE(col, @var1, @var2)
...
```